# Validatious callback functions

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm using the Validatious2 JS library for form validation.

I'm looking to add a piece of code to disable the submit button that only triggers after validation is succeeded and before the form gets submitted.

It seems that may be possible by using the `onSuccess` callback function from Validatious, but the Validatious site is down and I can't seem to find any reference on how to implement that callback.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Send us the URL or can you log the instance of your plugin?

Comment: https://github.com/cjohansen/validatious

And here's a blog post from the developer introducing the library:
http://stammen.no/en/brukervennlighet/skjemavalidering-med-javascript

Comment: The first sentence was hard to read so I've made it more easily scannable. You should also include your code here so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer in case someone else is looking.

The syntax is:
v2.CompositeFormItem.prototype.onSuccess=function(){}

The onSuccess callback function is called after successful validation and before form submit.